# Lower bound on Brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am trying to prove the unboundedness of variations in a Brownian motion in the following way: Consider the interval $[0,1]$ and let $B$ be the standard Brownian motion. We consider the sub-intervals $[\frac{i}{n}, \frac{i+1}{n}]$. The goal is to show that the summation $\sum_{i=1}^n |B(\frac{i}{n}) - B(\frac{i+1}{n}) |$ is almost surely unbounded.
I greatly appreciate any comment or hint to prove this.

My attempt: I was thinking on finding a lower bound for $|B(\frac{i}{n}) - B(\frac{i+1}{n}) |$ and show that this lower bound goes to $\infty$. We know $B(\frac{i}{n}) - B(\frac{i+1}{n}) \sim Normal(0,1/n)$. I was wondering if this is a good way to prove the above claim and how I can find a lower bound. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the quadratic variation of a Brownian motion?

Comment: @charlus, yes I know the quadratic variation of BM is finite. I have also seen the proof for unboundedness of variations of BM using the fact that it is nowhere differentiable. Here, I want to prove it in the way that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes. My point was that you can find an upper bound of $\sum_{i=1}^n\left(B\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)-B\left(\frac{i+1}{n}\right)\right)^2$ that depends on $\sum_{i=1}^n\left|B\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)-B\left(\frac{i+1}{n}\right)\right|$, which is essentially what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think since the quadratic variation in this case is bounded (it converges to the length of the interval which is 1 here), the lower bound you mentioned will not help. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct of course, but if you find a neat upper bound (e.g., your sum multiplied by something positive that goes to zero), it will suffice.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I will think about it.